# GDB Internals : Getting variable contents

Tags: api, gdb, internals

I want to add a new command to gdb source code, and I can do that using add_cmd.

In the command backend, I want to read contents of a few variable and print data in a more relevant format to me.

I can get the variable address using the following code:

```
struct symbol *sym;

sym = lookup_symbol ("my_variable_name", get_selected_block (&context_pc), VAR_DOMAIN, NULL);

printf_filtered ("Symbol %s is ", sym->ginfo.name);
printf_filtered (" at address 0x%x\n", SYMBOL_VALUE(sym));
```

This gives me the address of the variable:

```
(gdb) my_command
Symbol my_variable_name is  at address 0x8049684
```

However, I am not able to find what API will give me the contents of this variable. Need help with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the command backend, I want to read contents of a few variable and print data in a more relevant format to me.

It is *exceedingly* likely that you can achieve the same result using a [Python pretty-printer](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html). That requires no rebuilding of GDB, is easy to play with to get correctly, and provides a safe interface to GDB's internals.

> I am not able to find what API will give me the contents of this variable.

`target_read_memory()` is the lowest API that will give you the contents of memory at the given address.

Comment: Cool! target_read_memory() works great!
I will look into Python pretty-printer